# rcpp pass vector by reference

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have been dipping my toes into Rcpp in order to speed up some of the operations I currently perform in R. A problem I have encountered is when modifying a NumericVector passed by reference to a function.

In particular, the function below does not appear to alter the NumericVector (x)passed to the function:

```
void f1(NumericVector &x){
  NumericVector y(1);
  y[0] = 1;
  x = y;
}
```

On the other hand, the code below does:

```
void f2(NumericVector &x){
  NumericVector y(1);
  y[0] = 1;
  x[0] = y[0];
}
```

Based on this it seems as if you can't modify a NumericVector passed by reference to a function by assigning another NumericVector to it. Instead you have to modify it element by element. Is this correct?

This isn't necessarily an issue but it seems as if something like the first function should work and so I don't want to loop over each element of the vector unnecessarily.

Comment: This has been discussed many times before, look for previous discussions and search for 'Rcpp' and 'proxy object'. Also try to alter just `x` without creating `y`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Dirk. Just to be sure, is there no way of modifying multiple values in NumericVector with one operation (as you can for  std::vector)?

Comment: Of course you can. See the indexing examples at the Rcpp Gallery.